InstallShield InstallScript-MSI vs. InstallScript-non-MSI
I have myproject.ism and setup.rul files created by InstallShield (IS) 2016. How can I tell if the resulting installer is of the InstallScript-MSI flavor, or the InstallScript-non-MSI flavor?
I have tried various techniques, but I was unable to capture an MSI file. Also the product GUID is not listed in Windows uninstall folder. On the other hand the .ism file contains XML element named MSI. My current hypothesis is that my installer calls the MSI API, but that it does not create an MSI file.

Project type can be checked in General Information > General > Project File Name. Square bracket contains the project type.
As per the information provided, it seems you're using Installscript project. Installscript project doesn't use MSI.

I do not have access to InstallShield. I only have the .ism and .rul files. I also have the setup.exe and the .cab files.

You may try evaluation version of InstallShield. Otherwise, Check for database tables in .ism files. If these tables are not there then its should be Installscript project and it doesn't generate msi.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/database-tables

I see the FeatureComponents table. But not InstallExecuteSequence, InstallUISequence, MsiFileHash.

Ok then its not basic MSI project. Check for event handlers in .rul files.
https://docs.revenera.com/installshield21helplib/Subsystems/installshield21langref/helplibrary/LangrefEventHandlers.htm#langref_eventhandlers_1653732820_1057622
